# DateTime Covert on data post using WebApi?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am working on MVC 4 project with AngularJS. I have some date filed in my form. I am facing an strange issue when i post data to server using **$http.post()**. When i post any date like January 01,2013 is converted to 12/31/2012 on Server which gives an error on Server Post. I am not getting what is going wrong in my code base.

Hope you got my question.

Comment: sample code snippet would be useful, but the issue seems to be of timezone settings i.e, client is in different timezone than server, so the best thing to do is to convert date to unix date string and post and on server retrieve it back by converting again.

Comment: @Ravi have you made any progress with your issue?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with dates you have to be careful as to how they are serialised on the front-end and back-end. There is no standard.

Given your description and lack of other context though, I suspect it's a time zone issue.

- are you developing locally? i.e. are browser and server running on the same machine?
- (if not) what's the timezone the server is using? UTC?

Here's a post detailing some issues with JSON date serialization: ["On the nightmare that is JSON Dates. Plus, JSON.NET and ASP.NET Web API"](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx)

If you're not sure what's going on with serialisation you can use something like `curl` (*nix or maybe cygwin tool) or ["Fiddler"](http://fiddler2.com) to see the raw responses. Other things to do are to explicitly use date's `toString()` method to serialise the date as a string (and change on the server side too seeing you're using .Net) to explicitly control the deserialisation.

Comment: Yes i am developing locally and time zone in **UTC (+05:30)**.

Comment: How do i track the process of serilizing the date from front end to back end.

Comment: here's a post detailing some issues with JSON date serialization: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx